# When Datepicker is a field in a multifield, the date is not displayed

Tags: aem

I have datpicker in multifield. 
But on opening the dialog the authored values are not getting displayed.
When i do inspect element on dialog field it comes as

```
     *<input class="coral-InputGroup-input coral-Textfield" type="text" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="./date" value="2016-06-01T00:00:00.000+05:30">*
```

Can you please suggest what can be the issue and how to resolve it?

```
<field
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
        eaem-nested=""
        fieldLabel="Click on the + button to add Fields"
        name="./admission">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resouceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
            method="absolute"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <date
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/datepicker"
                        fieldLabel="Date of Event"
                        name="./date"
                        type="date"/>
                    <startTime
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/datepicker"
                        fieldLabel="Opening time of event"
                        name="./startTime"
                        type="time"/>
                    <endTime
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/datepicker"
                        fieldLabel="Closing time of event"
                        name="./endTime"
                        type="time"/>
                    <dayname
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                        fieldLabel="Dayname"
                        name="./dayname"/>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a misspelling in `sling:resouceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"`. You effectively don't have a `sling:resourceType` set.

However, there's also a more important issue. The Granite Multifield component doesn't work this way. Reading the documentation on the [granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield/index.html) we can see exactly how the data is saved and repopulated on subsequent dialog openings.

> The field to be included is defined in the subnode named field.
>   Regardless of the component used, Multifield assumes they all write to
>   the same property (defined by the name property of the field subnode)
>   thus the resulting value will always be multi value.
>
> When rendering existing entries, the Multifield will iterate over the multi value, get each value, set it in the field and let the field render it.

In order to accomplish what you're looking to do, you will have to write some custom code. A quick Google search revealed this two blog posts that can help you:

- http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/06/aem-61-touch-ui-composite-multifield-store-values-as-child-nodes.html
- http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/02/aem-6-sp2-touch-ui-multi-field-component.html

To reiterate, if you fix your typo, the fieldset and datepickers will show in your multifield. However, even though the dialog will display correctly, you won't be able to save or retrieve the data in this manner.

Comment: Hi @nateyolles. Is there a way to build a simples multifield for touch ui, without have to create custom js? I mean, just a simple one, do not even need layouts, fieldsets and columns. Is that possible? It seems that the problem (the same as mine) is when you try to organize you design with the metioned elements (layouts...).